# Android Studio Equivalate to CSS display grid

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

In CSS I can easily create a grid as in the picture below:

[image: Grid]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  margin: auto;
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

I started working with Android Studio today and want to achieve a similar effect? I've tried the linear layouts, but cannot get them to wrap or specify the number of columns and rows. Here's what I have so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But they are all in a line and acting more like a flexbox. There seems to be a grid layout, but it's under legacy so I'm assuming it's depreciated. How can I make a grid layout like the one above, specify the number of columns and rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GridLayout` is not deprecated at all.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
}
```

That's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:useDefaultMargins="true"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="2">

            <TextView
                app:layout_columnWeight="1.00"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1.00"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:text="1"/>

            <TextView
                app:layout_columnWeight="1.00"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1.00"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:text="2"/>

            <TextView
                app:layout_columnWeight="1.00"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1.00"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:text="3"/>

            <TextView
                app:layout_columnWeight="1.00"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1.00"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:text="4"/>

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</layout>
```

And also the documentation for it: [`androidx.gridlayout.widget`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/gridlayout/widget/package-summary).

---

However, for dynamic items you might want to use a `RecyclerView` with the `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: I was missing the implementation, that's why it was not working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how to make the above grid layout using

Android studio:

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8"?

 <LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent" 

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<GridLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:columnCount="2"

    android:rowCount="2">

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"

     android:layout_width="40dp"

     android:layout_height="40dp"

     android:text="1"

     android:TextSize="25"

     android:background="@drawable/border"

     android:textAlignment="center"/>

 <TextView

     android:id="@+id/textView2"

     android:layout_width="40dp"

     android:layout_height="40dp"

     android:text="2"

     android:TextSize="25"

     android:background="@drawable/border"

     android:textAlignment="center"/>

 <TextView

     android:id="@+id/textView3"

     android:layout_width="40dp"

     android:layout_height="40dp"

     android:text="3"

     android:TextSize="25"

     android:background="@drawable/border"

     android:textAlignment="center"/>

 <TextView

     android:id="@+id/textView4"

     android:layout_width="40dp"

     android:layout_height="40dp"

     android:text="4"

     android:TextSize="25"

     android:background="@drawable/border"

     android:textAlignment="center"/>

          </GridLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Go to res file and expand it, right click on the

drawable and click on Drawable resource file. On the

Drawable resource file write border as the file name

and ok.

border.xml

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

<shape

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re
s/android"

android:shape="rectangle">

 <solid

     android: color="@android:color/white"/>

 <stroke

     android: width="2dp"/>

  </shape>
```

Comment: Please see [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ...